# how to implement alfresco custom login component

Tags: authentication, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-maven

I'm Following This Tutorial On Alfresco's Platforme and I'm Stuck at this point

> You would typically connect to the remote authentication mechanism
>   to verify username/pwd...
>   this link to the tuto : [Authentication](https://docs.alfresco.com/community/references/dev-extension-points-authentication.html)

Answer (score 0):

This means you will authenticate your user from external sources like external database or from any other external rest api call which will give you response and based on that response you need to decide whether user is authenticated or not, if authenticated pass true else false.